# Why do proxy providers generate same proxy?

Tags: python-requests, proxy, request, http-proxy, request-headers

Proxy providers provide the same string of proxies multiple times for example;

```
endpoint.proxyprovidername.com:port
endpoint.proxyprovidername.com:port
endpoint.proxyprovidername.com:port
endpoint.proxyprovidername.com:port
endpoint.proxyprovidername.com:port
endpoint.proxyprovidername.com:port
endpoint.proxyprovidername.com:port
endpoint.proxyprovidername.com:port
endpoint.proxyprovidername.com:port
endpoint.proxyprovidername.com:port
```

Why's this done since the provided proxies are the same string?
Using the below as an example;

```
import requests

proxy: str = "endpoint.proxyprovidername.com:port"
proxies: dict = {
  'http': f'http://{proxy}',
  'https': f'https://{proxy}'
}

url: str = 'https://www.example.com'

response = requests.get(url, proxies=proxies)

print(response.text)
```

Does making use of the variable `proxy` makes any difference rather than iterating through a list of same string?